# Corona extract each character from string

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm beginner in game development using corona, can you please help me guys how to get every character in a word then add background image to it and make it clickable like in **4 Pics and 1 Word Game**. Can you please suggest some ideas or tutorial link. Thanks. So far I don't have enough reputation to put image here but here is the [Screenshot Link](http://houseofgeekery.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/photo-2.png)

Comment: So, your question is: write the code for you?

Comment: even just the idea sir or if you know some tutorial link for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some pieces that may help you
1. Iterate over each character

```
local str="Something"
for i = 1, str:len() do
    print(str:sub(i,i));
end
```

2. load image

   local img = display.newImage("images/" . letter . "1.jpg");

if you need anything specific ask here

Comment: thank you so much! I'm now able to get every character.

Comment: In my game there is a delete button for the recently entered character. Every character tapped I removed its event listener, then when the delete button is tapped I bring back the event listener again but error occured. Do you have any idea sir?

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over each character, try also this:

```
local str="Something"
for c in str:gmatch(".") do
    print(c)
end
```

(Actually, this iterates over each *byte* in the string, which may not be what you want if the string contains Unicode characters.)